# Why doesn't MOVWF affect the status register?

Tags: assembly, pic

I'm learning assembly, and it seems that `MOVF f,d` can be moved f to f, but the zero flag in the status register will be set, meaning it's useful to check if f is zero. Why doesn't `MOVWF` affect the status register?

Comment: This is a question about the fine details of a specific instruction of a specific architecture.  Please tag it to indicate *which* specific architecture you're talking about.  (Most questions which are badly tagged as simply "assembly" are actually about x86, which this clearly isn't.  I'm guessing PIC, but only because I used Google.  If I'm right, please add the [tag:pic] tag.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question probably talking about PIC MCPUs, so I have added `pic` tag.

PIC MCPUs have RISC architecture, which is high-optimised logic and that is the main reason why `MOVWF` will not to affect to the `Zero` flag in `Status` register.

When value is loaded in to `W` `(WREG)` the `Zero` flag in `Status` register is set, so there is no reason to be set again when we store that value with `MOVWF` instruction. This is useful in case that we must test the Zero flag after `MOVWF` instruction.